# how to handle initialization of class members in angular 1.3 with typescript 3

Tags: angularjs, typescript

We have an awful 3rd party product that is tied to angular 1.3 (long story).

How can I best handle initialisation of fields in typescript?  For example in this controller:

```
export class Controller {
  // Local state
  // choices: DropDown{}  // to make this non optional, I need to set strictPropertyInitialization to false,

  constructor(public choices: DropDown[]) {}
}

export function choiceListEditDirective(): IDirective {
  return {
    controller: Controller,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    template,
    restrict: 'E',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      choices: '='
    }
  };
}
```

Because of `strict` and `strictPropertyInitialization`, tsc does not like having non initialised properties that angular will be setting.

So I have 2 (maybe 1) choices, set `strictPropertyInitialization` to `false` in `tsconfig.json` or somehow use public field initialisation:

```
  constructor(public choices: DropDown[]) {}
```

But angular complains about this with the following error:

`[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: choicesProvider <- choices`

This is because angular must be looking for something to dependency inject.

How can I best handle this considering I am stuck in an ancient version of angular (sadly).

Comment: This is angularJS, not Angular.

Comment: Indeed, every field in a Controller's constructor is expected to be injected by AngularJS. It looks like it is a double binded value, so it has nothing to do in the constructor's parameters. Why don't you simply initialize it to null (or empty list if your controller manages it correctly) ?